# Bash shell copy files on the hidden directory

Tags: linux, bash, files, directory, copy

Need help with Unix script.

how do you use /bin/cp to copy files from /somepath/somedir/somewhere/.temp_folder
 to /somepath/somedir/somewhere/

my line

```
/bin/cp -r somepath/somedir/somewhere/.[!.]* somepath/somedir/somewhere/
```

the directory **.temp_folder**  Is copied but I want to copy only files

tia!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find <path> -type f -exec cp {} <destination path> \;`

this will copy only files, overwrite files with identical names, and you won't have source directory tree in the destination directory.